# BMW 328i 2009 - RPMs Jump when it’s on reverse

Tags: engine, bmw, rpm, 328i

My RPMs jump when it’s in reverse. Is this normal? But it stops after a while. I’m just curious.

Comment: Hi and welcome!  Please elaborate on your issue - do you have a manual transmission? Does the RPM jump in other gears?

Comment: I have an automatic transmission and it doesn’t jump on other gears . Only on reverse

Comment: Please modify your Question with the info.  Thanks!